# Regexp help, Match "0000-000 Text with spaces"

Tags: php, regex

Basically I need to match something like this:

```
0000-000 Text with spaces
```

Where 0000-000 and 0 is any number, followed by a space followed by arbitrary text, with spaces.

I have the numbers down:

```
/^\d{4}(-\d{3})?$/
```

but I'm having a hard time getting the text...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's close, but you would use this pattern to match the text as well:

```
/^\d{4}(-\d{3})? ([\w\s]+)$/
```

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> - `\d` any decimal digit
> - `\s` any whitespace character
> - `\w` any "word" character
>
> A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "***word***". The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by ***\w***.

Comment: This is kinda what he's asking about "I got the numbers down, but I'm having a hard time getting the text"

Comment: Heh, I would think it should be `([\w\s]+)` instead of `([\w\s])+`

Comment: orange Pills' response matches characters with accents, (á ã, etc) yours doesn't, I need to understand why.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: @AmandoFilipe because `.` will match everything while `\w` will only match `a-zA-Z0-9_`. If you want to match that kind of letters with `\w`, I think you should use the `u` modifier or add `(*UCP)` at the beginning of your expression.

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex

```
/^\d{4}(-\d{3})? .+$/
```

Answer (score 2):

For people who DON'T assume everyone just uses the standard U.S. English charset:

`/^\d{4}(-\d{3})? ([\p{L}\s]+)$/u`

`\p{L}` matches any Unicode codepoint that is classified as a letter, regardless of language. The `u` flag is required at the end so that PHP's PCRE engine expects Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match only text and spaces after the numbers, you can do:

```
/^\d{4}(-\d{3})?[ a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interactive regex editor (made for Ruby but works for php)

http://rubular.com/r/ocbo5Sea8m

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{3} .+
```

Seems to work